# c# Application Configuration File: AppSettings Reads Empty?

Tags: c#, configuration

This is my first time using an XML config file. In the solution explorer I right click, add, new item, application config. file.

I then edited the file to read...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>    
    <add key="Key1" value="1000" />    
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

...and tried to access it with...

```
Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Key1"));
```

...but it says that the parameter is null. I looked at just `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` and it's `AllKeys` property has dimension 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right-click on your project, choose Properties>Settings tab and edit your settings there because the config file is not the only place these values are stored at.
2. In your code use `Settings.Default.MySetting` to access the settings.

You'll need to add `using MyProjectName.Properties;` to your using statements in order to access the settings this way or you'll have to fully qualify it as `MyProjectName.Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting`...

Comment: Any reason onto why ConfigurationManager.AppSettings cant be used?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super old but I just encountered this opening an old project.  A reference to `System.Configuration` was missing.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure get information from `App.config` using  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["<Key name>"];` be sure to set your values inside  `<appSettings>` section.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />      
    </startup>
  
   <appSettings>
    <add key ="IntervalSeconds" value ="60000"/>
    <add key ="OutputPathLog" value ="\\myserver\hackingtrack\Projects\Log\"/>
    <!--Jorgesys si Elenasys sunt puisori-->
    <add key="InputFeeds1" value="https://cld.blahbla.com//portadaKick.json" />
    <add key="InputFeeds2" value="https://cld.blahbla.com//portadaKick.json" />
    <add key="InputFeeds3" value="https://cld.blahbla.com//portadaKick.json" />

    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Retrieving values:

```
   string intervalSeconds = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntervalSeconds"];
   string inputFeeds1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputFeeds1"]; ; 
   string inputFeeds2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputFeeds2"]; 
   string inputFeeds3 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputFeeds3"];
```